# Create components dynamically based on attribute selector

Tags: html, angular, typescript

### Context

In my application, admins can freely configure some forms that needs to be compiled by other users. Those forms can have an arbitrary number of inputs of predefined types (like integers, checkboxes, text and so on...)

This configuration comes from the server in this way (exemplified):

```js
{ fields: [
   { type: "typeA", maxValue: 50, ...},
   { type: "typeB", maxValue: 70, ...},
   { type: "typeC", maxValue: 40, ...},
   ...
]}
```

To handle this, i built a number of input components with an attribute selector:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component[type=typeA]',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field class="w100p" [floatLabel]="label != null ? 'auto' : 'never'">
    ....
`
```

---

### The Problem

How can i build a component via attribute selector specified in a **variable**?
I already tried with:

```
<div> 
  <component type="typeInVariable"></component> 
</div>
```

where `typeInVariable` has value `typeB`, but angular returns me an error: `Template parse errors:
'component' is not a known element:`

How can i solve this?
I also have created a stackblitz sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-xwb1ip).

Comment: Do you want to pass some value to your component? Then add an `@Input() type: string;` variable to your component. You also don't need the `[type=typeA]` in your selector.

Comment: My whole point is to have a "dynamic" selector. i may have multiple components (with different selector: `component[type=typeA]`, `component[type=typeB]` etc. ) and i would like to create them via a variable

Comment: But why? Why do you need multiple components? It should be enough to create one component with `@Input` variables and then create your forms dynamically. See [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use dynamic components here.

Some references:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

https://netbasal.com/things-worth-knowing-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-166ce136b3eb

I have had a similar requirement and it worked for me. Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: I am aware of dynamics components via typescript but i was searching for a template-only solution, if existant